# How to scroll view to Top of screen

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, scrollview

I have a EditText in my android NestedScrollView and I want it to go to top when It's focused, something like this:

[image]

I tried:

SmoothScrolling/Scrolling to a direct pixel,
SmoothScrolling/Scrolling to the top of the view(or bottom)

none of them work, and not even respond consistently.

Edit:

I got it, will leave the question for documentation porposes.

I got the ScrollView size with

```
scrollView.getBottom();
```

And then scrolled to the intended place using:

```
scrollView.scrollTo(0,2*scrollView.getBottom()/5); //size will vary from view to view
```

Comment: You want it to get to the top of the layout? First element in the layout?

Comment: exactly! That would be awesome

Comment: Can you post your layout?

Comment: I got it, edited my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for others who need a solution, here it is for `Java`:

```
/**
     * This function will scroll and bring a view to the top of scrollView
     *
     * @param view target view
     */
    public static void scrollToView(View rootView, ScrollView scrollView, View view) {
        rootView.clearFocus();

        int[] locationOfView = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(locationOfView);
        int viewY = locationOfView[1];

        int[] locationOfScrollView = new int[2];
        scrollView.getLocationOnScreen(locationOfScrollView);
        int scrollY = locationOfScrollView[1];

        scrollView.post(() -> scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, viewY + scrollView.getScrollY() - scrollY));
    }
```

And here is `Kotlin` extension function:

```
/**
 * Scrolls the ScrollView to bring a specific view to the top.
 *
 * @param target The target view to be brought to the top.
 */
fun ScrollView.scrollToView(rootView: View, target: View, extraTopMargin: Int = 10.dp()) {
    rootView.clearFocus()

    val (_, targetViewY) = IntArray(2).apply { target.getLocationOnScreen(this) }
    val (_, scrollViewY) = IntArray(2).apply { getLocationOnScreen(this) }

    post { smoothScrollTo(0, targetViewY + scrollY - scrollViewY - extraTopMargin) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your scrollView hasn't get enough time to calculate it's size? Did you try:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: will try that now, can you tell me more about why wouldn't it have time to calculate it's own size?

Comment: scrollView.post(Runnable { scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0) })